# Can omnibenevolence be seen as a limit to omnipotence?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, semantics, problem-of-evil

The existence of evil seems almost to be an arbitrary step in the problem of evil. This is because  an omnibenevolent being cannot have the capacity to act malevolently, which an omnipotent being must have.

It's not the most sound argument, but in essence what I'm asking is can,or must, an omnibenevolent being have the ability to act immorally?

Comment: This has already been asked and discussed at length http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/is-god-either-immoral-or-not-omnipotent